# numpy loadtxt StopIteration error

Tags: python, numpy

```
trainfile = open('train.csv')
features_train = np.loadtxt(trainfile, delimiter=',', usecols = (2,4,5,9), skiprows = 1)
labels_train = np.loadtxt(trainfile, usecols = (1,), skiprows = 1)
```

It throws `StopIteration` error in the third line.

Comment: Yes, because you exhausted the file iterator.

Comment: You can handle this gracefully using `try/except` if you don't want to raise the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should load once and split the data after  loading:

```
trainfile = open('train.csv')
all_data =  np.loadtxt(trainfile, delimiter=',', usecols = (1,2,4,5,9), skiprows = 1)
features_train = alldata[1:, ...]
labels_train = alldata[0, ...]
```